# jQuery not fading on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

I have a table and every time someone hovers over a cell I want it to become less opaque (opacity is default 0.85). Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("td").hover(function(){

        $(this).fadeTo(700,1);

            },function(){

        $(this).fadeTo(500,0.85);

    }); 
});
```

EDIT: It seems like the problem may be that nothing is firing when I hover, even when I add `alert('hi')` to the function, nothing happens

EDIT 2: If anyone still reads this question, I believe the reason it wasn't working when I asked this question is because I was creating the td elements asynchronously and they weren't there when the page as loaded. I believe I ended up using .on() instead of .hover(). Also, fading to 1.0 opacity was the desired effect (it started at 0.85 or 0.5 I forget). Thanks everyone

Comment: Table cells are weird when it comes to CSS and jQuery.  Post up a jsfiddle and we'll try to help.

Comment: Okay I've made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D96PA/

Comment: After adding jquery to your fiddle, and changing the script to fade to .5, it appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/u3D7j/

Comment: Your fiddle works fine once you include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D96PA/1/

Comment: wow that is such a silly mistake, thanks

Comment: since an answer of mine got shut down, (hard crowd `:)`) it's worth mentioning that `<td>`'s should be wrapped within a `<tr>` element. http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/tabular-data.html#the-table-element . namely, the `Content Model` does not include `<td>` as a child. only as a descendant

Comment: @sircapsalot the OP never revealed their HTML so why do you assume that their HTML is incorrect (aside from the quick comment)?

Comment: @Neal His jsFiddle was incorrect.  I felt it worth noting

Comment: @sircapsalot that is what a comment is for :-D

Comment: @Neal yea, i realize that. i deleted my answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use CSS

```
td {
    opacity: .85;    
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
td:hover {
    opacity: .5;    
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/bnrWK/

Comment: i like this answer.. no need to use jQuery for something so simple.

Comment: I want it to fade to that opacity which is why I used jquery in the first place, I know it may seem silly. edit: I will resort to this if the answer is not trivial, thanks

Comment: @SamCreamer updated -- now does a fade animation. Still no javascript.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. was not aware that this was possible, still learning!

Comment: @SamCreamer Be aware that this will not work with older browsers, as this uses css3.

Comment: @rlemon nope, I do not believe so. Sorry.

Comment: This is CSS 3.0... isn't supported by all major browsers (Olde IE doesn't support it... for sure)

Comment: @rlemon IE10+  Which means none on xp

Comment: actually IE8+ so long as you don't care about the transitions.

Comment: @rlemon the transition is what we're all talking about.

Comment: Well in that case... Screw 12 year old OS's

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you have your functions backwards:

(You were fading up to 1 on mouseover, and fading down to .85 on mouseout)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("td").hover(function(){

        $(this).fadeTo(500,0.85);

    },function(){

        $(this).fadeTo(700,1);

    }); 
});
```

Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/bZ3gX/

Comment: still doesn't work, I think that nothing is firing when I hover over $("td")

Comment: @SamCreamer, make sure that you are including jQuery in your jsFiddle.. I noticed the link up there that you didn't.

Comment: Yes, that would also help!!

Comment: fading to 1 on mouseover is what I had intended to do, got it working now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The opacity you are fading to, 1.0, is fully opaque, not transparent.

Try having it fade to 0.5

Answer (score 0):

You may have to predefine the opacity for the table cell prior to having the hover work.

```
table tr td {
    background: grey;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The rest is just using your jQuery code.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vdHDD/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use css transtions also

```
td:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
    }
td{
opacity:.85;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/D96PA/4/

Not sure why you set the second function to 0.85 instead of 0.5.  I changed it to 0.5. Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("td").hover(function(){

            $(this).fadeTo(700,1);

                },function(){

            $(this).fadeTo(500,0.5);

        }); 
    });
```